# How to read/write to sftp server with Deno

Tags: sftp, deno

Is there any example or is there any library like [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) for interacting with an sftp server in Deno?

Answer (score 1):

As of Deno 1.30.0, it is possible to use NPM packages directly.

```
import { Client } from "npm:ssh2"

const conn = new Client();
```